# Printing a JSON/HTTP response from a Cisco endpoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Please check over my Python code for a HTTP GET operation using the `requests` library, and provide any potential pointers for improvement.

```
import requests

token = input()

payload={}

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/yang-data+json",
    "Content-Type": "application/yang-data+json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(token),
}

url = "https://sandbox-xxxx.cisco.com/restconf/data/native/router/bgp"


try:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False, timeout=10)
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
    print(f"An HTTP Error occured: {errh}")
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
    print(f"An Error Connecting to the API occured: {errc}")
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
    print(f"A Timeout Error occured: {errt}")
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
    print(f"An Unknown Error occured: {err}")
else:
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.json())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, Reinderien.

I am just starting in Python so please excuse any "noobness" from myself.

This is just a cisco IOS-XE device I am testing on in the lab where code runs fine and with no issues without any exceptions, I just wanted to add some exceptions in to make my code as optimal as possible.

There is a load of different and conflicting info out there, so I thought I would cobble together what I thought and ask some experts for their own opinion rather than some random online blog.

Comment: Thank you for understanding. I have updated my original response to include the full code. 

I am just trying to get a decent set of exceptions that I could then apply to any future HTTP requests. I did read about what you mention about a form of catch all is not a good idea, so this is what prompted me to put my first post up on here.

Comment: This doesn't execute, right? `my_url` and `url` are two different variables

Comment: It does execute. Apologies, That was a mistake on my part, I have edited the code again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is the entire script,

1. it doesn't need to exist and you can just invoke `curl` directly; and
2. we can be a little more forgiving on exception-handling best practices.

There isn't a whole lot of value in separating your `except`s for different exception types. This is one of the few use cases where a catch-all `except Exception` is not a bad idea. If you print the `repr()` of the exception object using the `!r` format specifier, it will show you the exception type and content while omitting the traceback. If you do want to see the traceback, just delete your `try`/`except` entirely and let the default printing take effect.

`occured` is spelled `occurred`.

Don't call `input()` prompt-less.

`verify=False` is risky. If the certificate does not have a valid trust chain, then you should pull the certificate and trust it explicitly either in your OS or within `requests`.

Consider using `pprint` to print your JSON document.

When you print the status code you should also print the reason string.

### Suggested

```
from pprint import pprint

import requests

token = input('Please enter your bearer authentication token: ')
sandbox = input('Please enter your sandbox ID: ')

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/yang-data+json",
    "Content-Type": "application/yang-data+json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
}

try:
    with requests.get(
        url=f"https://sandbox-{sandbox}.cisco.com/restconf/data/native/router/bgp",
        headers=headers,
        data={},
        verify=False,
        timeout=10,
    ) as response:
        doc = response.json()
except Exception as e:
    print(f'An error occurred: {e!r}')
else:
    print(response.status_code, response.reason)
    pprint(doc)
```

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly the kind of feedback I was after. I have a few questions off the back of what you said but I'll take them to Google-fu.

Thanks, Reinderien again, appreciate you sticking with me and my ignorance throughout the post.

All the best.

Comment: @pythontestuser You can ask here, too; I'm happy to answer (and if the chain gets too long it'll just be moved to chat)

Comment: Thanks Reinderien, I really appreciate your time. 

For your point 1 you made. I started as testing initially with curl. Then I moved towards creating a python script as my end goal is going to be having variable substitutions that a user can enter in a gui (or another system can interact to or from.)

I'm a network engineer, so of course I read Python was the way to go about this, so this is why I have started to focus mainly on Python. Would you still say this is the incorrect approach I am looking to take?

For point 2, nothing further as you explained everything perfectly, thanks.

Comment: When expanding to a simple GUI or any kind of non-trivial substitution Python is a good choice.

Comment: OK, cool. appreciate the confirmation.